# What is invertible matrix in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

I learned linear algebra for 1 year and I never thought if there is any geometrical/visual idea behind it? I just know that $AA^{-1} = A^{-1}A=I$.

I hope there is something visually that I can grip that concept on.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you view a matrix as instead a linear transformation, whereas $A$ will "do" something,  $A^{-1}$ will "*undo*" it.  E.g. scale by a factor of two and rotate clockwise $60^\circ$ is undone by scaling by a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ and rotating counterclockwise $60^\circ$

Comment: Look up rotation transformations in the plane. Geometrically, the inverse will be the same magnitude rotation in the opposite direction, and algebraically the inverse can be found in the "usual way" or by replacing $\theta$ with $-\theta.$ For rotation matrices, the identity $A^{-1}A=I$ can be viewed as saying that a counterclockwise rotation through an angle $\theta$ followed by a clockwise rotation through an angle $\theta$ takes you back to where you started.